# Send print job from PHP on Linux to Windows without samba

Tags: php, html, windows, printing

I have a billing web app running on a Linux server and clients accessing it from Windows terminals. The client need to print some information from the app instantly (without any preview or user confirmation) to the local printer (on Windows).

I know that I can send print jobs from PHP but I would have to set up samba properly and found the right drivers and is a very strange printer so this option is discarded.

I need some kind of application that runs on Windows and can recieve print jobs through the network and print locally.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround, I just enabled "silent printing" in Firefox doing as follow:

> All you need to do, is set a preference up on the CLIENT BROWSER, you
>   can't do this through the web, you must have direct access to the
>   local browser.
>
> Go to about:config (Type this in the address bar)
>
> Right click on any preference and select "NEW" > "BOOLEAN"
>
> type: print.always_print_silent
>
> Hit OK
>
> type: true
>
> Restart the browser. The next time you start the
>   browser, any javascript print(); command will print directly to the
>   printer using the currently configured print settings.

Source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=48336

In Chrome you can create a new shortcut to the chrome.exe app with the flag --disable-print-preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following javascript on the page you want to print:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        window.print();
        window.location.href = "Location/to/go/to/after/sending/current/page/to/print";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: As soon as the page is loaded, this script will send the page to the current default printer on the client's machine, and then move on to the next page on the third line. (User will see a glimpse of the page). You need to make sure that you have formatted the page using appropriate media css to get your intended output.

Comment: This doesn't work, the web browser keep freezed asking for the printer and then it forwards to the next page.